# jquery deep linking, forward and backward buttons

Tags: jquery, deep-linking

I have a deeplink set up I've made for my site, and it works with exception of the forward and backwards buttons, and I'm a little unsure how to update what I've done.  The url changes but the content doesn't unless you hit refresh.

here is an example of it working: http://www.klossal.com/index2.html#color_dance

and here is the code:

```
        // taked anchor from browser i.e '#bow' , '#bow-003'
        var id = window.location.hash;

        // check is it valid anchor
        if (id.match("#") != null | id.match("#undefined") != null) {


                $(id).ready(function () {
                    $(id).trigger("click");
                });
            }
        $(".iso").click(function () {
            window.location.hash = $(this).attr("id");
        });
```

Comment: You are using a single pipe for OR - did you mean to make this? `if (id.match("#") != null || id.match("#undefined") != null) {`, or did you want an AND operator?

Comment: umm, to be honest I'm not sure, would that fix the issue?

Comment: No it wouldn't fix the issue - but could fix some other issues in the code - might even prevent you from tearing your hair out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(window).on('hashchange',function() {
        var id = window.location.hash;

```
    // check is it valid anchor
    if (id.match("#") != null | id.match("#undefined") != null) {


            $(id).ready(function () {
                $(id).trigger("click");
            });
        }
```

});